# How to print inside unit tests in Java?

Tags: java, junit

I have written a few unit tests using JUnit and am running them via the main method using a test suite. However, I noticed that the System.out.print statements that I put inside my unit test methods are not outputting to the console like I expected.

Is there a simple way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Try debugging to see if there are any errors before your `print` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `System.out.println` normally. It will print when you run the test.

Comment: `stdout` is usually redirected to `null`. Use `System.err.println` instead to see the output.